# Jquery - having to add surplus [0] to Jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've come across this problem several times, and at first tried to ignore it.
I have a select element:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="my_select" name="contracting_party_legal_entity">
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I want, say, to populate my select programmatically with options. 
Looks like I should use `$('#my_select').appendChild($option)` to achieve this, but no! Unless I write `$('#my_select')[0].appendChild($option)`, I get an error `appendChild is not a function`. Why is the reason for this necessity to use the surplus [0] ? Is it smth wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: `appendChild` is a native method, jQuery objects don't support it. `append` would be the nearest jQuery method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is a jQuery function. It returns an Array of all matching elements.

Therefore to select particular element you need to choose index of array.

You may use `$('#my_select').get(0).appendChild($option)` and `appendChild` is vanilla javascript function it works on element not on jquery object. Try jQuery **append** function.

Example of jQuery append function:

```js
$("#test").append("<option>hello</option>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option>Select box</select>
</select>
```

Comment: Completely satisfied. Got it. So if I get the element by plain-vanilla JS function getElementById, I will be able to use appendChild without any index?

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild` is native JavaScript. `$(...)` is a jQuery function which returns a [jQuery collection](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

jQuery has its own built in [`append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which can be used instead:

```
$(...).append(...);
```

> The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first child, use `.prepend()`).